# Why have duplicated properties for Image size?

Tags: .net

When checking out the specification for the [`Image` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx), I noticed there are three ways to access the `width` and `height` of the object:

1. Use `Height`/`Width` property, which returns `Int32`
2. Use `Size` property, which returns `Size` that has `Height`/`Width` as `Int32`
3. Use `PhysicalDimension` property, which returns `SizeF`, that has `Height`/`Width` as `float`

What is the reason behind this ? Are they guaranteed to be always the same ? Is one preferred over the other ?

The third one seems to make some sense since it could be either the size in pixels, if the object is a bitmap or the size in millimiter units if it is a metafile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Size` is guaranteed to be the same `Width` and `Height` because [the source code for it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs.html#3a10364d45ca5409) is simply

```
public Size Size {
    get {
        return new Size(Width, Height);
    }
}
```

I can't speak for the .NET development team but the reason they have both is likely for convenience. Use whichever is more useful for your use case.

For the 3rd option, it appears you answered your own question already when you asked. It is used for when you have metafiles.